# How can I make my material into glass?

Tags: transparency, glass

I'm following a tutorial on making frosted glass, and I'm already stuck with making it transparent.
I brought the roughness down, transmission up, and turned on the screen space reflections...
[image: This is sort of what it looks like...]

Comment: Under the material settings, make sure "blend mode" is set to something other than opaque (alpha-blend and alpha hashed work well). You also have to reduce your alpha below 1 (if you are using eevee).

Comment: That fixed it perfectly. Thanks.